# MySQL SELECT over two tables

Tags: mysql, select

This is my current code

```
SELECT * FROM pn_queue WHERE email = '2'
```

Now i want to extend is with an "AND" wich is in another table. Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM pn_queue WHERE email = '2' AND FROM pn_cats WHERE cat = '2'
```

How can i make it? I will be thankfull for any ideas or solutions.

Comment: Is there any dependencies between this tables ? If yes then use **JOIN** as mention by @Jean-François Savard Else use **UNION ALL**

Comment: What do you mean with dependencies? I have a table with subscribers (id, name, email, code and so on) and a table with categries (id, code, cat) now i want to add a mail to a queue when something happens. To look wich should become a mail i want to look if a sub has a special flag and if he is in a special category. So the select must be over to tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `Join`

```
select * from pn_queue a
  join pn_cats b on a.pn_cats_id = b.id -- Change this condition to whatever should match on both table.
where b.cat = '2'
  and a.email = '2'
```

Not sure if the join condition is actually right as you don't give enought information, but just modify the condition `a.pn_cast_id = b.id` if it ain't.

**Edit :** Just realized in your example cat and email are both equals to `2` so if it should be the match value then the correct query would simply be :

```
select * from pn_queue a
  join pn_cats b on b.cat = a.email
```

For more information on SQL Join, you should check this thread [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins). It explain the difference between all possible joins with diagrams/examples etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry for the bad example. Do you know a side with a good description for the needed function?

The two single select will be 1) SELECT * FROM pn_subs WHERE status = '1' ---- 2) SELECT * FROM pn_cats WHERE cat = '50'

But the second one should be an AND to the first one. So that i become only data from the first table when on the first table status=1 and on the second table cat=50.

Comment: `select * from pn_subs where status='1'
union all
select * from pn_cats where cat='50';`

Comment: You guys have sended me to the right thoughts and ideas! union all don´t work in my case. join is the right way. The code for me must be: SELECT * FROM pn_subs JOIN pn_cats ON pn_subs.code = pn_cats.code WHERE pn_subs.status = 1 AND pn_cats.cat = '2'
I think it would be easier for you guys next time when i use sqlfiddle or something else and give you more code and infrmations. Sorry for my fault. Thank you very much!